# What criteria must be true to create a new session when Spring Security's IF_REQUIRED session creation policy is used?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-session, session-management

Spring Security's [API Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.1.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/http/SessionCreationPolicy.html) for `SessionCreationPolicy` says the following for the `IF_REQUIRED` property, which I believe is the default:

> Spring Security will only create an `HttpSession` if required

And that's all it has to say about that. But what does that mean? When does Spring determine that a new session "is required"?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything easily findable defining "required" (in `ifRequired`).  My guess is that if the rest of your configuration requires a session then it will be created by Spring Security, but not otherwise.  I'd upvote but I'm out of votes for the day.

Comment: Thanks Jim. If your thought is true, I'd have to ask what criteria must be true for Spring to determine that your configuration requires a session. I'm really looking for specifics here.

Comment: This is probably going to require a thorough reading of Spring session management (not just Spring Security) and maybe digging through the source or working up a set of tests to characterize the behavior.  The joys of Open Source :-)

Answer (score 0):

Spring allows to define beans with scope *session*:

```
@Component
@Scope("session")
public class MyComponent
```

or from spring 4.3:

```
@Component
@SessionScope
public class MyComponent
```

I guess when at run-time such kind a bean is required then a session must be created.